# Accidentally recorded a Teams meeting, should I apologize to meeting attendees?

Tags: professionalism, meetings, online

Thank you for reading through.

I was in a Miscrosoft Teams meeting (virtual online). I was trying to turn on the live caption so I could know what people were talking about if the voice wasn't clear. But I accidentally pressed on the start recording button which is adjacent to the live caption button, then the software started to record the meeting with a notice showing up on everyone's screen saying "xx (my name) is recording this meeting".

When I noticed it I quickly stopped the recording, but still, everybody knew that I was recording for a while.

I think I missed the best timing to apologize for this, should be during the meeting and say hey I'm sorry, wasn't intended to record.

Now the meeting is over, should I apologize to them after? How should I put it? Or will people care about this?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

S

Comment: How long did it take you to notice? If you stopped it immediately, the others probably realized you misclicked.

Comment: Write a casual, apologetic message into the "chat" that relates to that meeting.

Comment: Can't you say something like "Has anyone tried to use auto-caption? Does it work well? I tried to activate it and I hit record by accident." This gives the intent, context and may provide you with info.

Answer (score 10):

If nobody mentioned it then probably nobody cares.  Talk to your manager (or the manager of the team whose meeting you were in if it wasn't your team) and explain the situation, exactly as you explained it here, and say you've deleted the recording (make sure you actually do delete it) and apologize.  It should be nothing serious.

Comment: This is a dangerous assuption. People don't always speak up if something bothers them. That said, talking to the boss (maybe asking for advice) is a good start.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that the best timing would have been right in the meeting. However, if you have another meeting with the same people soon you may however, raise it casually the next time.

So, suppose you were greeting one another at the beginning of the meeting, you could mention:

> Oh, yes, I sometimes have connection issues. I generally turn on the live caption so I can even if there are drops or voice isn't clear, but it isn't without dangers. Last week when trying to enable live caption I accidentally enabled recording!

While it's fine to mention it casually, you shouldn't worry about it. If you disabled it by your own a few seconds after enabling it, it's clear enough that it was some kind or mistake. Most people should have understood it like that, and not really minded about your error.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to say anything because you didn't do anything wrong. When configured to allow recording, Microsoft Teams tells meeting participants, "By joining this meeting you have given consent for it to be recorded." Recordings are also made available in a very obvious way to all participants so anyone who wants to see what you recorded will know that you only recorded for a brief period and that they consented to being recorded. If the administrator wants to limit you (or other users') ability to record they can block recording.